# How to drag an event from FullCalendar back to external list

Tags: fullcalendar

In FullCalendar I can drag-and-drop an event from an external list into the calendar. But I also need the reverse. So could anyone please let me know hwat are the steps to implement the drag-and-drop of a FullCalendar event from the calendar back to the external events list?

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the external-dragging demo and posted the code to the comments on http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=550.  Hope it helps

Comment: one problem- when dragging out it deletes everything on the day..oops

Comment: Would be nice to have some of the most important code on this site instead of just a link.. I'm unable to check the project out for whatever reason.